# JSF 2 custom component with h:commandLink inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2, foreach, composite-component, mojarra, uirepeat

I developed a custom component (inspired by [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html) by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)) that contains a `ui:repeat` tag displaying the list of clickable table pages.
Inside the loop block there is a `h:commandLink` that calls asynchronously an action, posting a parameter. The parameter value changes at every loop. Here's the page code:

```
[...]
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.pager.pages}" var="loopPage">
    <li>
        <h:commandLink 
            action="#{cc.attrs.pager.changePage}"
            value="#{loopPage}"
            rendered="#{loopPage != cc.attrs.pager.currentPage}"
            immediate="true"
        >
            <f:param name="selectedPage" value="#{loopPage}" />
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="#{cc.attrs.render}" />
        </h:commandLink>

        <h:outputText 
            value="#{loopPage}" 
            rendered="#{loopPage == cc.attrs.pager.currentPage}"
        />
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
[...]
```

Now, the `cc.attrs.pager` component attribute is noting else that the view-scoped backing bean, whose `pages` and `currentPage` attributes are visible through getters, and `changePage`method is the action to call. The `cc.attrs.render` component attribute is the target to be refreshed after every action execution. Here is the relevant bean code:

```
[...]

private Integer[] pages;
private int currentPage;

[...]

public Integer[] getPages() {
    return pages;
}

public int getCurrentPage() {
    return currentPage;
}

[...]

public void changePage() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
        .getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getRequest()
    ;

    String page = request.getParameter("selectedPage");
    changePage(Integer.valueOf(page) * rowsPerPage);
}

public void changePage(int firstRow){
    this.firstRow = firstRow; //Set the first result to be returned
    loadDataList(); // Load requested page.
}

[...]
```

The initial render is perfect: all the page links are correctly shown and the current page number is not linked, as desired. The problem reveals going to another page: nothing happens.
Although the `h:commandLink` action is posted with the exact loop parameter value, the response returns always the same page (the first).
Debugging it, I observed that the execution doesn't enter in any of the two `changePage` methods. 
I'm not sure if this issue is related to `ui:repeat`, but omitting it, I can tell that the same mechanism does work for other purposes.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try replacing `<ui:repeat>` with `<c:forEach>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain me why I am to do so?

Comment: Does it work? If you are using Mojarra, `<ui:repeat>` is buggy. You should not use it.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Mojarra 2.0.6. The bug should be [this one](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1807). The solution you give works fine. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Another issue: using `c:forEach` on `cc.attrs.pager.pages` the first page rendering shows nothing. I think that's because the collection is not yet initialized when evaluated by `c:forEach`. Is it correct?

Comment: The issue seems to be present also in Mojarra 2.1.6